# In Scala, How to pass type parameters into Seq[] in runtime

Tags: scala, type-parameter

I want to pass type-parameters into Scala Collections like Seq, Array, etc.

For example,

```
 val a: Seq[Int];       // it's easy to specify a type parameter "Int"

 val b: Seq[xxxxxxx];   // I want to receive a type of Seq from other like functions parameters or any other variables in runtime.
```

is it possible in Scala ?

Actually I want to do this...

```
def fun( arr1 : Any, arr2 : Any, arr3: Any ) {
   val seq: Seq[???] = Seq(arr1, arr2, arr3); 
   myOwnLibrary(seq); // Seq[Any] is not available as a myOwnLibrary's parameter; 
}
```

Comment: Type parameters (just like generics in Java) happen at compile-time and are erased at runtime. What are you really trying to do? Please show a more complete code snippet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/782/type-parameterization-generics#t=201611291020496494203

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but possibly this is what are you trying to do:

```
scala> def mkArray[T : ClassTag](elems: T*) = Array[T](elems: _*)
mkArray: [T](elems: T*)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])Array[T]

scala> mkArray(42, 13)
res0: Array[Int] = Array(42, 13)

scala> mkArray("Japan","Brazil","Germany")
res1: Array[String] = Array(Japan, Brazil, Germany)
```

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/ClassTag.html